# What is the meaning of the following two-order Taylor expansion for calculating the change of loss function?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know what Taylor series is but still stuck with the two-order Taylor Expansion 
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H16ih.png)

I can't understand what is the meaning of the function

The Lsel is as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCh8j.png)  which they were tried to minimize.

This function is from the paper "Visual Tracking with Fully Convolutional Networks"

I was wondering if there is any help can be provided. Many Thanks!

Comment: Which norm is used to define $L_{\mathrm{sel}}$ ?

Comment: They didn't mentioned but I guess it's 2-norm

Comment: If $\mathbf{M}$ is a matrix, it may just be the Frobenius norm then. 
$$ L_{\mathrm{sel}}(\mathbf{M}) = \mathrm{tr}\big( (\hat{\mathbf{M}} - \mathbf{M})^{\top} (\hat{\mathbf{M}} - \mathbf{M}) \big). $$
In that case, if you want to minimize $L_{\mathrm{sel}}$, you do not need a Taylor expansion of $L_{\mathrm{sel}}$. You just need the gradient of $L_{\mathrm{sel}}$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that after parameter learning using back-propagation converges,
they fix the model parameters and select the feature maps according to their impacts on the loss function. They said that's why they used a Taylor expansion